# Phalcon multiple table select resultsets always complex?

Tags: phalcon

Whenever I select from more than one table in the same query (using phql, builder, or criteria) the result is always an instance of *\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Complex*, which is a bit... complex to deal with. Is there a way of making a UNION or some syntax that will return the result in *\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple* form?

Comment: What trouble are you running into when using Complex resultset ?

Comment: I was wondering why it has no convenience method like toArray

Answer (score 1):

As of 2.0.7 there is no native framework way to turn a complex resultset into an array. You have to incorporate something like the method below.

```
function toArrayComplex(
    \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Complex $results,
    $isFlat = false
) {
    $array = [];
    if (!$isFlat) {
        foreach ($results as $i => $rows) {
            foreach ($rows as $modelName => $row) {
                $array[$i][$modelName] = $row->toArray();
            }
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($results as $rows) {
            $temp = [];
            foreach ($rows as $modelName => $row) {
                $temp[$modelName] = $row->toArray();
            }
            $array[] = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $temp);
        }        
    }
    return $array;
}
```